# How to avoid automatic roundoff of values in bar-chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The latex code below round-off the values of bar-chart. I need the values to stay intact. For example, 0.8197 shouldn't round-off to 0.82.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={baseline, seq\_1,  seq\_2, seq\_3, seq\_4},
            xtick=data,
       nodes near coords,
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (baseline,   0.8197)
                (seq\_1,  0.7006)
                (seq\_2,  0.5134)
                 (seq\_3,   0.8314)
                  (seq\_4,   0.8449)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4` to the `axis` options to have a fixed number format with 4 digit precision. See [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) v3.0.1a Section 92 p946

**EDIT**

As noted by Peter Grill, `/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4` acts on the complete axis, so prefer `every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,precision=4}`
to only apply this specific format to the numbers on top of the bar chart.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={baseline, seq\_1,  seq\_2, seq\_3, seq\_4},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,precision=4}
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (baseline,   0.8197)
                (seq\_1,  0.7006)
                (seq\_2,  0.5134)
                (seq\_3,   0.8314)
                (seq\_4,   0.8449)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Better to use `every node near coord/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,precision=4}` so that the `number format` is _only_ applied to the data.  In this case, the visual output is the same, but try applying anohter option such as `zerofill`.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks, I updated muy answer taking into account your advice

Answer (score 1):

By default `nodes near coords` prints `\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta`. You can tell it to use `precision=4` by doing

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
```

instead of just

```
nodes near coords
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={baseline, seq\_1,  seq\_2, seq\_3, seq\_4},
            xtick=data,
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=4]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (baseline,   0.8197)
                (seq\_1,  0.7006)
                (seq\_2,  0.5134)
                (seq\_3,   0.8314)
                (seq\_4,   0.8449)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```