# TikZ: Print Zeros after comma in nodes

Tags: pgfplots

I have a data set like:

```
1 1.1
2 2.02
3 5.00
```

I use this line, to print the value next to the bar shart in Ti*k*Z:

```
every node near coord/.append style={
        anchor=west,
        rotate=90,
    },
```

Point 1 should become 1.10, point 2 is perfekt with 2.02 but point 3 should become 5.00 and not only 5 as it is right now.

Comment: Please provide an MWE.

Comment: `pgfplots` is not TikZ, `pgfplots` is based on TikZ. `nodes near coords` is a `pgfplots` concept, you won't find it described in the manual for TikZ. So more appropriate to say you're making a bar chart with `pgfplots` (because you could do it in TikZ, without `pgfplots`). That said, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427561/ but you also want `fixed zerofill` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, xtick=data,ymax=7,
every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west,rotate=90},
nodes near coords*={%
  \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill, precision=2]\pgfplotspointmeta}
]
\addplot table{
1 1.1
2 2.02
3 5.00
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The picture does not match the code.  The font is different.